# How to converting Corona setReferencePoint to Anchor?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I had a Corona app that was working with `display.setRefencePoint`, but when trying to run it now, it isn't working.  After looking online it seems I need to use `Anchors` now.  Below is the current section I had, but im having trouble converting it to `Anchor` points, please help.

```
background = display.newImage ( "Background.png");

--Sets its position reference point
background:setReferencePoint ( display.TopLeftReferencePoint );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
background = display.newImage ( "Background.png");
-- to make reference point at TopLeftcorner
background.anchorX = 0.0;
background.anchorY = 0.0;
```

For more info, visit: [Tutorial: Anchor Points in Graphics 2.0](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/)

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Karishna's answer but there is also an alternative way to get support of `setReferencePoint` by adding `graphicsCompatibility`field in `Config.lua` file as :

```
application =
{
    content =
    {
        graphicsCompatibility = 1,  -- Turn on V1 Compatibility Mode

        width = 320,
        height = 480,
        scale = "letterbox"
    },
}
```

Latest Version `Graphics 2.0` has compatibility with `Graphics 1.0` by Setting `V1 Compatibility Mode` as mention in above code.This is special mode that significantly reduces the effort required to migrate. This mode is `off` by default More you can visit [Here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/migration_v1.html#TOC).